# Simple scalable work/message queue with delay

Tags: message-queue, rabbitmq, gearman, beanstalkd

I need to set up a job/message queue with the option to set a delay for the task so that it's not picked up immediately by a free worker, but after a certain time (can vary from task to task). I looked into a couple of linux queue solutions (rabbitmq, gearman, memcacheq), but none of them seem to offer this feature out of the box.

Any ideas on how I could achieve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I've used BeanstalkD to great effect, using the delay option on inserting a new job to wait several seconds till the item becomes available to be reserved.

If you are doing longer-term delays (more than say 30 seconds), or the jobs are somewhat important to perform (abeit later), then it also has a binary logging system so that any daemon crash would still have a record of the job. That said, I've put hundreds of thousands of live jobs through Beanstalkd instances and the workers that I wrote were always more problematical than the server.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, I've been looking into beanstalkd the past couple of days and it looks great. And you're right, worker logic and management is tricky :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use an AMQP broker (such as RabbitMQ) and I have an "agent" (e.g. a python process built using pyton-amqplib) that sits on an exchange an intercepts specific messages (specific `routing_key`); once a timer has elapsed, send back the message on the exchange with a different `routing_key`.

I realize this means "translating/mapping" `routing keys` but it works. Working with RabbitMQ and python-amqplib is very straightforward.

Comment: I thought about this, but if the waiting agent gets killed while it's waiting for the timer to elapse, the message never gets added to the queue.

Maybe I could fix this by having a second, permanent queue, and an agent with multiple internal timers.

Still, it seems like an ugly workaround.

Comment: Well, dealing with this failure-mode is part of the game. I would be surprised if the functionality you are asking gets mainstream in AMQP Brokers out-there since it goes against the main goal: minimize latency.

Comment: Thank you for your replies. I think I will give beanstalkd a try, it seems ok, and supports the "delay" I was talking about.